# What is the difference between a mat3 and a float[9], in terms of size?

Tags: glsl

In my GLSL Compute Shader, I've declared a struct called `ParticleData`, and when I read in part of my buffer as a `mat3`, the size (which I assess by looking at the output) is different than if I use a `float[9]`.

I haven't been able to find a definitive source explaining the `mat3` structure. he data I'm writing to my buffer is simply 9 floats, stored in an `std::array<float,9>`.

What is the difference between a `mat3` and a `float[9]`, in terms of size?

Comment: I'm 90% sure it depends on implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the GPU and driver.

Due to the way many GPUs work a mat3 may be padded internally to take 12 floats of space arranged as `[x0, y0, z0, pad][x1, y1, z1, pad][x2, y2, z2, pad]`.

A float[9] will take 9 floats of space but then may effectively be padded (or not) to 12 floats by adding 3 floats of padding at the end `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8][pad, pad, pad]` for the next data to align properly. Although those don't count as part of its size the next data item may start after the padding.

This is because some GPUs can only access data aligned to 16 bytes (4 floats) or are otherwise very limited in how they can access the data for performance reasons.

Some more info from the official OpenGL site: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Memory_layout

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  Right now I'm using `std430`.  Is there a recommended way then to write a matrix to a buffer, and read it in the ComputeShader?  In my case, I don't actually care about this particular matrix in my compute shader, but have it in my buffer so that I can read it in my vertex shader.  At least in my vertex shader I can better define the matrix with `glVertexAttribPointer`, but I'm asking this question to make sure I won't have the same kind of issues.  Thanks

Comment: I just use a mat4

Comment: Implemented a `mat4` and it works very intuitively.  Thanks